# How to save state of menu toggle button across requests with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am building a website for mobile devices and I have this jQuery function that shows or hides the main menu depending on what the user selects:

```
$(function() {

    $('#nav_toggle').on('click', function(event) {  
        $('#main_nav').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("collapsed");
        event.preventDefault();  
    });

});
```

My problem is: How can I keep (or *not* keep) the `collapsed` class in my menu across requests?

Right now, the user has to toggle the menu on every page.

It would be nice to somehow store it across requests, maybe by setting a cookie?

How can this be done?

I am fairly new to jQuery, so a code sample would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTML5 I would rather go for localstorage:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to attach query string or hash to your URL and pass state of menu that way. Or you could use cookie.

Here is the code for setting/getting cookie in JavaScript.

```
function setCookie(value) {
    var expires = "; ";
    if (config.cookie_duration) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + config.cookie_duration);
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + "; ";
    }   
    document.cookie = "SELECTED_STATE=" + value + expires + "path=/";
}

function getCookie() {
    var name = "SELECTED_STATE=";
    var c_arr = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < c_arr.length; i++) {
        var c = c_arr[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);

        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Disclaimer: I found the basic idea a long time ago somewhere on the web, I do not remember from where exactly. It's modified to suit needs of one project I was working on, so I just copied it here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save cookie and use it across all pages

`document.cookie="username=John Smith; path=/";`

Get cookie code

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

on footer write something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(getCookie(cookiename)!=''){

      $('menuIdOrClass').addClass('class Name Which keep menu open')

     }

});
```

Soruce - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing the value in a cookie (like you mentioned) and then setting it on page load.

Download the jQuery cookie plugin [**here**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Now set the value:

```
$.cookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value");
```

And then in your [`document.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler you can pull the value..

```
$.cookie("cookie_name);
```

..and set it appropriately with something resembling your current [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, [user1041953](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041953/user1041953), for bringing `localStorage` to my attention. It's a lot easier to use than cookies I think.

This is what I ended up with:

```
$('#nav_toggle').click(function(event) {
  $('#main_nav').toggle();
  localStorage.setItem('display', $('#main_nav').is(':visible'));
  event.preventDefault(); 
});

var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
if (block == 'false') {
  $('#main_nav').hide();
} else {
  $('#main_nav').show();
}
```